# Cypher Query Trying to get all nodes with 3rd degree connection, while all nodes follow the same constraints

Tags: filter, graph, neo4j, nodes, where-clause

I'm struggling with writing this query

I want to find all of the workers,
who have friends of 1st degree, 2nd degree AND 3rd degree,
who follows 2 conditions.

but if one of the above connections does not apply to the conditions,
I do not want it to be in the output

for example:
the relationship is friend.
conditions are:
City: "New Delhi"
age >= 29
friend , friend of friend , friend of friend of friend - Direction irrelevant
if the node has a friend that not apply to the conditions even though it has another path that does apply I do not want it

[Graph DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAY1y.png)

```
MATCH (u1)-[:friend]-(u2)-[:friend]-(u3)-[:friend]-(u4)
WHERE(u1.address = "New Delhi" AND u1.age >= 29)
AND (u2.address = "New Delhi" AND u2.age >= 29)
AND (u3.address = "New Delhi" AND u3.age >= 29)
AND (u4.address = "New Delhi" AND u4.age >= 29)
RETURN DISTINCT u3.name
```

This query gives me all the nodes that I wanted and more..
it does not filter the ones that have a relationship with someone that not apply the conditions
I will be more clear:

a-b-c-d path that apply the conditions MARK it P
a-q-w-v q OR w OR v do not apply the conditions MARK it N
because of P a will be in the output but because of N it should not be

[Who stand the requirements and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ILC.jpg)

I added this picture for graphic explanation
the mark with black circle is the output-> every one in chain apply the conditions
Green is apply the conditions
Red is not.

Hillel, Tor and Dror. They apply the conditions but the have friends or friend of friends or friend of friends of friends that does not. So they will not be in the output.

The out put for my Query is the black circles and the 3 names above how to I do it with out those 3.

sorry for all the extra details I tried in neo4j manual to find an answer but with no luck

Comment: Your logic at the end of your post is very confused and unclear. Please write English sentences that parse. I will say this: your query is symmetric in the MATCH and WHERE clauses. That means any match will yield two rows: (u1)--(u2)--(u3)--(u4) is in your query if and only if (u4)--(u3)--(u2)--(u1) is in your query. If you have loops in your data, which your graphic would indicate not but I don't know, then you could get four rows for every match! It might be a good idea to introduce directions in your query to eliminate the symmetry.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment,
That the Idea of friendship it has loops :)
My query did not give me the answer I wanted that why Im trying to find here help to improve my knowledge in neo4j.

The point is this if someone in the requested chain does not stand the requirements nobody from that chain will be in the output.

Comment: I added another explanation with a picture :)

Comment: In your WHERE clause you can use things like `AND NOT EXISTS()` and put stuff inside, but this approach might not be flexible enough for what you're describing. I'm honestly not sure how to do what you want to do. Maybe you should call up Neo4j support and see if someone can help you out.